# Django UUID Autoassign as Name of file in S3

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-1.5, postgresql-9.3

I like clarifying that I'm new to Django.

```
Versions:
Django 1.5
Python 2.7
PostgreSQL 9.3
```

I have a webapp that uploads a file to AWS S3, this works currently. I would like to name the file the name of the `contentid` field that gets auto assigned a V4 UUID on upload. I'll try and pick out the relevant information and post it here. I'm not sure where I would gather this information and declare it for the name.

**View**

```
def upload_content(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ContentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        new_content = Content(name=request.POST['name'],accountid=request.user.id,public=False,url=request.POST['name'],uploaddate=datetime.now(),viewcount='0',file = request.FILES['file'])
        new_content.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect('/Console/Content/')
```

**Model**

```
class Content(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    accountid = models.IntegerField(max_length=34)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    uploaddate = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    viewcount = models.IntegerField(max_length=34)
    public = models.BooleanField(max_length=1)
    contentid = UUIDField(unique=True,editable=False)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='content')

@classmethod
def get_content_list(cls, account):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT name, contentid, public, uploaddate, id FROM webapp_content WHERE accountid=%s ORDER BY uploaddate', [account])
    ret = cursor.fetchall()

    return ret
```

Answer (score 0):

So I have somewhat of an answer, but I'm still left with an issue

model:

```
def generate_new_filename(instance, filename):
   ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
   filename = '{}.{}'.format(uuid.uuid4().hex, ext)
   return (filename)

class Content(models.Model):
   file = models.FileField(upload_to=generate_new_filename)
```

view:

still the same as above, how do I write to my sql the newly generated filename on save in place of `request.FILES['file']`

The outcome:

file get's written the correct variable, url does not